# Stack Overflow mobile app

Tags: support, badges, android-app, ios-app

I recently installed the Stack Exchange app. I wish to know if accessing the website using the app counts as a day visited on the site.

I am close to earning the enthusiast badge, will it disrupt the streak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**. Visiting the site from the mobile app does count the visiting days. So don't worry about your badge.

Comment: Are you sure? I've visited the site each day for more than 15 days using the iOS App and I opened the badge overview a few minutes ago where the badge's counter/progress says "1/30". I've visited the site by browser today for the first time in two weeks. Seems that the counter only recognized the browser visits.

Edit: ignore that. I checked the badges on meta.stackoverflow.com didn't know these were counted separately :D